# Set Asp.net chart values

Tags: c#, asp.net, mschart

```
int successful = students.Where(p => p.Successful == 1).Count();
int unsuccessful = students.Where(p => p.Successful == 0).Count();
```

How can I insert this values to a single row bar chart?

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: i did it with binding a list to my chart before.But i didn't find any source to how to assing like this two int values to y-fields on chart component i was asking that actually.I didn't mean to say do it for me.